# Como setar um campo select com um valor pré-definido

Tags: html, input, html-tags

Eu preciso fazer com que o campo select me traga a informação que esta em <%=endereco.getEstado()%> na qual retorna "SP". No input para cidade, eu consigo pegar o valor de <%=endereco.getCidade()%> na qual retorna "Mogi das Cruzes" e assim traz no input este valor já preenchido. Eu não consigo fazer isso para estado, utilizando value="<%=endereco.getEstado()%>" como em cidade, o campo de estado não está retornando nada, simplesmente fica no primeiro option:"selecione uma opção". Alguma sugestão de como eu posso pegar o valor de <%=endereco.getEstado()%> e preenche-lo automaticamente no select?

Observação: os dados contidos em <%=endereco.getEstado()%> e <%=endereco.getCidade()%> são do tipo String.

Segue o código abaixo:

```
<tr>
<td><label for="cidade">Cidade:</label></td>
<td><input size="20" type="text" name="cidade" value="<%=endereco.getCidade()%>"></td>
<td><label for="uf">Estado </label></td>
<td><select type="text" name="uf" value="<%=endereco.getEstado()%>"/> 
        <option value="">Selecione uma opção...</option>
        <option value="AC">AC</option> 
        <option value="AL">AL</option> 
        <option value="AM">AM</option> 
        <option value="AP">AP</option> 
        <option value="BA">BA</option> 
        <option value="CE">CE</option> 
        <option value="DF">DF</option> 
        <option value="ES">ES</option> 
        <option value="GO">GO</option> 
        <option value="MA">MA</option> 
        <option value="MT">MT</option> 
        <option value="MS">MS</option> 
        <option value="MG">MG</option> 
        <option value="PA">PA</option> 
        <option value="PB">PB</option> 
        <option value="PR">PR</option> 
        <option value="PE">PE</option> 
        <option value="PI">PI</option> 
        <option value="RJ">RJ</option> 
        <option value="RN">RN</option> 
        <option value="RO">RO</option> 
        <option value="RS">RS</option> 
        <option value="RR">RO</option> 
        <option value="SC">SC</option> 
        <option value="SE">SE</option> 
        <option value="SP">SP</option> 
        <option value="TO">TO</option> 
    </select>
</td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não lembro muito bem de jsp
Mas a ideia é essa

```html
if(endereco.getEstado().equals("sp")){ 
  //manda printar o html aqui
  //exemplo
  <option value="<%=endereco.getEstado()%>" selected>SP</option> 
}
```

Comment: Funcionou. Eu não precisei utilizar nenhum if. Só que como ele retorna apenas a sigla, eu alterei todos os outros options para siglas também. O comando que funcionou: <select type="text" name="uf" value="<%=endereco.getEstado()%>" id=uf required/> 
            <option value="<%=endereco.getEstado()%>"><%=endereco.getEstado()%></option>

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda!

Comment: Tranquilo, desculpa as confusões, sou novo aqui.

Answer (score -1):

Use o html para deixar marcado uma opção

```html
<select name="estado">
  <option value="sp" selected>São Paulo</option>
</select>
```

Comment: os dados contidos em <%=endereco.getEstado()%> podem variar, pois trata - se de um resultado de uma consulta de um banco de dados, este código que você postou não ajuda muito, pois traria uma opção fixa

Comment: faz um if entao.

Comment: faz um if entao, verificando o valor que voce deseja selecionar.